# Cassandra - TypeError: "value" argument is out of bounds

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra

I am getting following error frequently. Any idea ?

```
TypeError: "value" argument is out of bounds
        at checkInt (buffer.js:1041:11)
        at Buffer.writeInt32BE (buffer.js:1244:5)
        at Encoder.encodeInt (/gps/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/encoder.js:522:9)
        at Encoder.encode (/gps/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/encoder.js:1310:18)
        at ExecuteRequest.writeQueryParameters (/gps/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/requests.js:129:38)
        at ExecuteRequest.write (/gps/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/requests.js:96:8)
        at whileProcess (/gps/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/writers.js:209:50)
        at Immediate.next (/gps/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/utils.js:882:5)
        at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
        at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
        at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set a value to something > 2^31-1 which is the max represented value in signed 32 bit integer.